# opengl doesn't draw when bufferdata comes from the heap

Tags: c, opengl

I'm trying to draw some triangles in opengl. This is the first method I tried, and this one works.

```
...
StaticVertexData vertices[6] = {
        {{ 255,   0,   0, 255}, { -0.90, -0.90, 0.0f}},
        {{   0, 255,   0, 255}, {  0.85, -0.90, 0.0f}},
        {{   0,   0, 255, 255}, { -0.90,  0.85, 0.0f}}
}
...
glGenBuffers(numBuffers, buffers);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[ArrayBuffer]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices),
                &vertices[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
...
```

This works good, and i get one triangle on the screen.

However, If I allocate the vertices array on the heap with malloc, the window is blank.

```
...
StaticVertexData* vertices = (StaticVertexData*) malloc(verticesCount*sizeof(StaticVertexData));
vertices = (StaticVertexData[6]) {
    {{ 255,   0,   0, 255}, { -0.90, -0.90, 0.0f}},
    {{   0, 255,   0, 255}, {  0.85, -0.90, 0.0f}},
    {{   0,   0, 255, 255}, { -0.90,  0.85, 0.0f}}
};
...
// same as in the previous example
```

Why is this? Is it impossible to send data from the heap to the gpu? Does it have to first be allocated on the stack?

Comment: If you're doing `sizeof(vertices)` with the second version, you won't get the right size. It will return the size of a pointer which is probably 4 or 8 bytes.

Comment: Of course! Now I feel stupid. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't what you expect this to do:

```
vertices = (StaticVertexData[6]) {
    {{ 255,   0,   0, 255}, { -0.90, -0.90, 0.0f}},
    {{   0, 255,   0, 255}, {  0.85, -0.90, 0.0f}},
    {{   0,   0, 255, 255}, { -0.90,  0.85, 0.0f}}
};
```

To be honest I wonder why your compiler didn't error out on that. Unless you're using some compiler specific language extension you can not assign an (existing) array a bunch of new values in a single statement. The notation you use is only valid for array initialization.

Add to that, that the `sizeof` of a pointer symbol is different as an array symbol.

Comment: That code worked for me. What I did wrong was that later on I used sizeof(vertices) for the size of the vertices. Since the vertices was now a pointer, it didn't work.

Comment: @sighol: You then probably (unknowingly) used a compiler specific language extension.